# How to print the names of the values in the enums which are interdependent in C++

Tags: c++, enums, stl

Our platform code will get callbacks from 3rd party library and the call back function will receive two arguments. First argument is part of one enum A and it represents one of the may enums which will come as second argument. For example,

```
enum a = {fruit, book, bike, car, sport, none}
enum f = {apple, mango, banana, none};
enum bo = {C, C++, Java, Python, none};
enum bi = {herohonda, lml, none};
enum c = {camry, carrola, altima, nissan, honda, none};
enum s = {cricket, tennis, volleyball, none};
```

First parameter in callback represents one of the values in enum a. Second parameter is dependent on first parameter. If first parameter is fruit, second parameter will be one of the values in enum f. If first parameter is book, second parameter will be one of the values in enum bo.

Right now we are just printing the values we are getting from callbacks directly so those values will be some things like 1, 0 or 2, 1. But it is difficult to know immediately by looking at these numbers in thousands of logs. I wanted to print the names instead of values. One way is to use if conditions for the parameters but it is not efficient. I planned to use maps. But I am not able to think what will be the second parameter in the map. First parameter (key) in the map will represent first parameter in the callback. How to define second parameter (value) in the map. Will it be a structure which contain a string (to represent the string of first parameter of callback) and a map which contain second parameter of the callback and the string representation some thing like below.

```
map <int second_parameter, string second_string> second;
struct map_struct
{
    string first_string;
    map <int, string> second;
};
map<int first_parameter, map_struct *stru> map;
```

Is this correct or is there any other efficient way to print names instead of just numbers.

Comment: Using a  lot of enums like this is something of a code smell - you may want to rethink your design.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Those values are coming from third party vendor library. We don't have control over them.

Comment: I would create a map per enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a **lookup table**, the simplest form could be something like this:

```
std::string enums[5][6] = {
    {"apple",     "mango",   "banana",     "none"                    },
    {"C",         "C++",     "Java",       "Python", "none"          },
    {"herohonda", "lml",     "none"                                  },
    {"camry",     "carrola", "altima",     "nissan", "honda", "none" },
    {"cricket",   "tennis",  "volleyball", "none"                    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Steeve. This is the simple solution.